# why view.findViewsWithText(..) method not returns any gone views?

Tags: android

Why `myView.findViewsWithText(..)` method not returns any views with `Visible.GONE?` (i use View.FIND_VIEWS_WITH_CONTENT_DESCRIPTION flag as the last parameter).

`findViewById` method returns them but i need to get them base on their `contentDescription` attribute.

```
public ArrayList<View> Dest=new ArrayList<View>();
wrapperView.findViewsWithText(Dest, "MyContentDescription", View.FIND_VIEWS_WITH_CONTENT_DESCRIPTION);
```

And now Dest.size() is zero; if visible of them equals View.Visible, then size will be 2 (or etc).

thanks.

Comment: `if visible of them equals View.Visible, then size will be 2` you mean, if the views are visible the value is correct?

Comment: thanks for reply.
yes. when those are visible, the count is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use a trick for solve this problem. (because i have used the `contentDescription` so much in my project.)

my usage was in items of a `RecyclerView`. in this class per item creates once and binding process of it occures when that item appears on screen.

i use first character of value of `tag` attribute for determine `Visibility` of my views (that have `contentDescription`). then in `Constructor` of my custom `ViewHolder`, i found all  desired views (that have specific `contentDescription`) and checked first character.

for example if it was '*', i set its `visibility` to `GONE` or if was '&' i set it to `INVISIBLE`.

this process happens before draw view on screen, so everything is great.

Thanks for all replies. Thanks you @Sagar.

Answer (score 0):

First try cleaning the project .

if problem is there then use the below code.

Please use the below code

```
 String mButtonName = "descreption";
    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(mButtonName , "id", getPackageName());
```

That's the way you get in int(id) from string, but you can do the same using reflection which is supposed to be way faster.

```
public static int getId(String resourceName, Class<?> c) {
    try {
        Field idField = c.getDeclaredField(resourceName);
        return idField.getInt(idField);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("No resource ID found for: "
            + name + " / " + c, e);
    }
}
```

You can use it like this

```
getId("button", R.id.class);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but:
my question is not this. i want to get all views with "MyContentDescription" as contentDescription attribute, no get them by their ids.

this manner is worked when visible of them is View.VISIBLE